# Citing a few pages of a book in a link

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

In my bibliography (I use `natbib`) I wanted to use `@inbook` so that I could cite the author name, the edition, the publishing house, the year of publication and the page numbers in my thesis. I thought that inbook was the most apt bibliographic index for my job. The entries look something like this

```
@inbook{a,
    author = {Anton, H.},
    title = {title},
    booktitle = {Calculus: A New Horizon, 6th ed.},
    date = {1999},
    OPTbookauthor = {bookauthor},
    OPTeditor = {editor},
    OPTeditora = {editora},
    OPTeditorb = {editorb},
    OPTeditorc = {editorc},
    OPTtranslator = {translator},
    OPTannotator = {annotator},
    OPTcommentator = {commentator},
    OPTintroduction = {introduction},
    OPTforeword = {foreword},
    OPTafterword = {afterword},
    OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
    OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
    OPTmaintitle = {maintitle},
    OPTmainsubtitle = {mainsubtitle},
    OPTmaintitleaddon = {maintitleaddon},
    OPTbooksubtitle = {booksubtitle},
    OPTbooktitleaddon = {booktitleaddon},
    OPTlanguage = {language},
    OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
    OPTvolume = {volume},
    OPTpart = {part},
    OPTedition = {6th ed.},
    OPTvolumes = {volumes},
    OPTseries = {series},
    OPTnumber = {number},
    OPTnote = {note},
    OPTpublisher = {Wiley},
    OPTlocation = {Newyork},
    OPTisbn = {isbn},
    OPTchapter = {chapter},
    OPTpages = {p324-327},
    OPTaddendum = {addendum},
    OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
    OPTdoi = {doi},
    OPTeprint = {eprint},
    OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
    OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
    OPTurl = {url},
    OPTurldate = {urldate},
}
```

But, the output comes out to be very limited as this:

[image: bib]

I don't exactly understand what is the issue or don't exactly know whether there's a better way to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your bibliography style?

Comment: Looks like your *template generator* is set up for use with `biblatex`. Normal bibliographystyles do *not* know `date` but `year` and `month`. `booktitle` should be known by most BibTeX styles.

Comment: @Johannes_B So what should be the way to address the problem?

Comment: Which program gave you all the `OPTbookauthor` etc. stuff? Jabref? Endnote? Citavi? Mendelew? Probably there are settings to tweak to use the basic bibtex fields, instead of the modern `biblatex` fields. Or use `biblatex`  instead -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: @Johannes_B No, I just clicked the bibliography option and selected inbook from my texstudio so as to fill in the details myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have bib file and TeX file together in one compilable MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@inbook{a,
  author    = {Anton, H.},
  title     = {Calculus: A New Horizon},
  year      = {1999},
  edition   = {6},
  series    = {series},
  publisher = {Wiley},
  chapter   = {chapter},
  pages     = {324--327},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{plain} %
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting page]